# How to change the color of text in a declarative way in Qt QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a really basic GUI that I am making using Qt Quick Designer. When a button is clicked I want some text to change color. So here is what I have for the code:

```
onClicked: {

     if(displayText.color == "#ff0000") {
           displayText.color = "Black";
     }
     else if(displayText.color == "#000000"){
           displayText.color = "Red";
     } 
}
```

So this works when I run it, yet when I try to go to the Qt design view it says that "Imperative code is not supported in the Qt Quick Designer". Am I doing something wrong or is this just a Qt quirk that I am encountering? I know that there are ways to handle this in C++ but I was hoping to do it all in QML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just ignore the warning. Your code is okay, only that Qt Quick Designer can't yet run scripts or properly handle some script bindings. I suggest though that you use states instead of scripting the property changes. It will result in much cleaner and less redundant code:

```
onClicked: state = (state !== 'clicked' ? 'clicked' : '')

color: '#ff0000'   // or #000000, if that's your default color

states: State [
   name: 'clicked'
   PropertyChanges {
      target: displayText
      color: '#000000'
   }
]
```

Qt Quick Designer handles states very well (it shows them at the top), where you can select a state and change property values within the designer.

Answer (score 1):

You case just use simple boolean flag indicating color:

```
property bool colorFlag: false
...
color: colorFlag ? "black" : "red"
...
onClicked: colorFlag = !colorFlag
```

Or you can use something like this:

```
MouseArea {
    id: myMa
}
...
color: myMa.clicked ? "black" : "red"
```

This way is much cheaper than with states.